# Filter while mapping a list of object using reduce

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I would like to map a list of devices but not everyone of them, so I need to have 
some sort of filter in my map function.

here is what my map function looks like

```
get activities() {
    return this.props.screenProps.store.activities.map((sensor) => {
      return {
        id: sensor.SensorID,
        type: sensor.SensorType,
        timestamp: sensor.EventDate,
        key: sensor.SensorType,
      }
    })
  }
```

I would like only to return sensor with an id higher than 5, so I tried this
but it did not work.

```
get activities() {
    return this.props.screenProps.store.activities.map((sensor) => {
    if (sensor.SensorID => 5){
    return {
            id: sensor.SensorID,
            type: sensor.SensorType,
            timestamp: sensor.EventDate,
            key: sensor.SensorType,
        }

    }
}
```

I have read around that reduce will be the way to go, I tried to make it work, but 
without any success. any help?

Comment: `reduce` is meant to "reduce" your array to one return value. That may be one element, an aggregate, or any number of things. While you could use `reduce` to filter, it would be forcing it. The most efficient and clear way would be by using `filter` then `map`. `filter` will return the element *only* if your callback returns `true`. `map` will return something for every iteration, even if that something is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming SensorID is a number and not a string, can you please try this

```
get activities() {
    return this.props.screenProps.store.activities
      // Filter out records for which SensorID is more than or equal to 5.
      .filter(sensor => sensor.SensorID >= 5)
      // Use that filtered array to map it in a new one.
      .map((sensor) => {
      return {
        id: sensor.SensorID,
        type: sensor.SensorType,
        timestamp: sensor.EventDate,
        key: sensor.SensorType,
      }
    })
  }
```

If you are keen on using reduce for this, you can try the below snippet

```
get activities() {
    return this.props.screenProps.store.activities
      .reduce((acc, sensor) => {
        // Push the element to final array only if the SensorId >= 5
        if (sensor.SensorID >= 5) {
          acc.push({
            id: sensor.SensorID,
            type: sensor.SensorType,
            timestamp: sensor.EventDate,
            key: sensor.SensorType,
          });
        }

        return acc;
      }, []);
  }
```

Comment: this worked like a charm, can you please, if you don't mind give me some explanation how this works? thank you

Comment: Added the comments in the code. I hope those are helpful.